# Using unicode character in a (resourcebundle) properties file

Tags: java, unicode, properties, resourcebundle

I want this text to be printed into the run log:

```
loadedLanguage = Det laddade språket är sv_SE.
```

But in the log it turns into

```
Det laddade sprÃ¥ket Ã¤r sv_SE.
```

So I´m wondering, how do I use unicode characters inside my properties file?
This is the code that loads and prints the text:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("assets.pokemon.lang.loading", currentLocale);
    log(messages.getString("loadedLanguage"));
```